# Change x ticks in Regplot Seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, seaborn

Is it possible to change the "names" of the x ticks in a regplot using `seaborn`?

I have a dataset (`dataset`) with categorical variables, and I am trying to plot a linear regression on this:

```
import seaborn as sns
fig  = sns.regplot(x='Cond_L', y='RT', data=dataset, x_estimator=np.mean)
```

`Cond_L` seems a numerical variable but it is a categorical one with the following possible values: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.

However, when plotted, my x-axis rages from 1 to 4 but in steps of 0.5, not 1.

So my questions are (1) how to have only four ticks; and (2), how to change the numbers into text, i.e. `Cond1`, `Cond2`, `Cond3`, `Cond4`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find this solution:

```
ax.set(xticks=np.arange(1, 5, 1))  #limit the number of ticks to 4
ax.set_xticklabels(['Cond1','Cond2','Cond3', "Cond4"]) #rename ticks
```